# Flutter how to build a Widget list from data passed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

Im new to Flutter and I am trying to figure out how write a function that builds a widget beased on the data being passed from FirstScreenPageView() to SecondScreenPageView()?

More specifically:

```
class nameCard extends StatelessWidget{
const nameCard({
  Key key, this.firstName, this.lastName
}): super(key:key);
final String fistName;
final String lastName;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Container(
    child: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
          Text(fistName), 
          Text(lastName),
       ],
    ),
  ),
}
};

class FirstScreenPageView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: RaisedButton(child: Text('Send'), onPressed:(){
          ///Send nameCard Widget to SecondScreenPageView here})
    );
 }
}

class SecondScreenPageView extends StatelessWidget {
   List<Widget> nameCardList = [];
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
       children: nameCardList,
      ),
    );
   }
 }
```

How do I append nameCard from FirstScreenPageView to SecondScreenPageView's nameCardList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass second screen page view by constructor.

```
class FirstScreenPageView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: RaisedButton(child: Text('Send'), onPressed:(){
          ///Send nameCard Widget to SecondScreenPageView here})
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SecondScreenPageView(nameCardList: cardList),
          ),
        );
    );
 }
}

-------
class SecondScreenPageView extends StatelessWidget {
   final List<Widget> nameCardList;

   SecondScreenPageView({this.nameCardList});

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
       children: nameCardList,
      ),
    );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This passes the cardList to SecondScreenPageView however, what I am trying to do is pass a single widget nameCard to SSPV and append that nameCard to the nameCardList in there. Hope that clarified my question

Answer (score 0):

use instead a namecard not a list then add it to the list in the second screen and create a class namecard to use it for implementation before sending to the second screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NameCard {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;

  NameCard({this.firstName, this.lastName});
}

class FirstScreenPageView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    NameCard nameCardToSend = NameCard(firstName: 'name', lastName: 'lastName');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Send'),
              onPressed: () {
                ///Send nameCard Widget to SecondScreenPageView here})
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                  return SecondScreenPageView(
                    nameCard: nameCardToSend,
                  );
                }));
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreenPageView extends StatelessWidget {
  final NameCard nameCard;

  SecondScreenPageView({@required this.nameCard});

  List<NameCard> nameCardList = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    nameCardList.add(nameCard);
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(),

      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(nameCard.firstName),
          SizedBox(
            height: 11,
          ),
          Text(nameCard.lastName),
          SizedBox(
            height: 11,
          ),
          Text('Or in a Row'),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                width: 11,
              ),
              Text(nameCard.firstName),
              SizedBox(
                width: 11,
              ),
              Text(nameCard.lastName),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

sorry forget to add appBar: AppBar(), in the SecondScreenPageView so you can go back to the first screen

if that it please accept it as an answer see you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is fine and all but how do you do so without changing the view when the button is pressed? The .push() method will change from my current FirstPageView to SecondPageView